# Facebook og:image tag still allowing other thumbnails

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph

For my website, I've set

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.jondaou.com/resources/fthr.jpg" />
```

Everything works as expected (facebook finds and uses that thumbnail) EXCEPT:

When I go to post the site on Facebook, the thumbnail I specified is the first of 3 options. Facebook allows two other thumbnail images, which it found on my webpage.

How do I get facebook to use my < og:image > thumbnail exclusively, and not allow users to choose another one when they post?